# Export one of my friend lists

Tags: facebook, export

I know how to export **all** my friends (using backupify or others), but now I just want to export **a specific list**. How can I do this?

By exporting, I just mean their ID. I don't need any other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the Facebook UI, you need to utilize Facebook API which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Indeed. Actually I have found a trick without the API: Go to the group page, clkick "See all", scroll all the list, then "see generated HTML" (feature name may vary with browser), and then just filter: sed -e "s/li class/\n/g" | grep "friendListItem checkableListItem selectedCheckable" | sed -e "s/.*value=\"//g" | sed -e "s/\".*//g" | grep -v "Done"